# SQL Time passed since

Tags: mysql

I searched, and I tried the examples, but every script is incorrect!

### Here's the script I'm using just for testing

```
mysql_query("Delete FROM ScannedIDs WHERE 'datetime' >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)") or 
die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("Select * FROM ScannedIDs WHERE 'datetime' >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)") or 
die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo "Found $rows results!";
```

---

Here's the MYSQL data

```
                                        steamid             datetime
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198035301803   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561197984607788   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561197965902616   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198043885314   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198040227469   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198054594853   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198008404239   2015-01-06 01:40:06
Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   76561198021278627   2015-01-06 01:40:06
```

---

At this time, it's the same exact date, it should return 0 results!
24 hours from now, it's susposed to return 8 results.

I don't understand why it's returning 8 results, when a day did not pass by yet!

Comment: the condition should be ...WHERE datetime <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)")

Comment: Write a backtick character instead of a single quote (`'`) to quote the column name `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> WHERE datetime >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

There is no need of **`Single Quote`** `'` for a COLUMN.

Also in delete query you are **`deleting all the record matching datetime >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)`**

In Select Query you are **`retreiving records that matched datetime >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY).`**

How you will get record then as you deleted already. **`You will always get ZERO RECORDS`**